# Can I fix a non-positive definite correlation matrix to study partial correlations?

Tags: partial-correlation

Simple question. I have many correlation matrices $\mathbb C$. I want to build a partial correlation matrices using the inverse $\mathbb C^{-1}$, e.g.:

$$\mathbf {P}_{i,j} = \frac{(\mathbf {C}^{-1})_{i,j}}{\sqrt{\mathbf {(\mathbf {C}^{-1})}_{i,i} \cdot \mathbf {(\mathbf {C}^{-1})}_{j,j}}}$$

The thing is in my particular situation every matrix $\mathbb C$ is not positive definite: many eigenvalues are arbitrarily smaller than 0.

I know I can make it positive definite (at least in my case) by shrinking all non-diagonal elements towards zero, e.g. $C_{i,j} := \tanh{(0.999 \cdot \tanh^{-1}(C_{i,j}))} $, but this doesn't appear correct to me nor I have seen it applied anywhere else.

What should I do?

Comment: I presume you mean C are covariance matrices. How are your non-positive definite covariance matrices generated (computed) and how far do they deviate from positive definiteness? For example, is smallest eigenvalue negative with magnitude less than 1e-8, which might be roundoff error away from positive definiteness? See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63817/generate-normally-distributed-random-numbers-with-non-positive-definite-covarian/230600#230600 for some ways of making positive definite. Your results (inverse diagonal elements) will be very sensitive to what you do - not good.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone $\mathbb C$ is a correlation matrix. It's the pearson coefficient denoting pairwise correlations between some input vectors. The smallest eigenvalues are indeed $\mathcal{O}(1E-8)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Major edits vs. original version.

Per your comments, $C$ is a correlation matrix, so it has diagonal elements all equal to 1.

If you can compute the correlation coefficients more accurately, then do so. Use of higher precision might be a good idea. If that solves the problem, fine.

Otherwise, you need to make C a positive definite correlation matrix in order that its inverse will have a positive diagonal.  To do so, you can try to find a positive definite correlation matrix which is as close as possible to the original matrix in the Frobenius norm sense (square root of sum of squared differences of all elements).  Proceed per my solution method B at [Generate normally distributed random numbers with non positive-definite covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63817/generate-normally-distributed-random-numbers-with-non-positive-definite-covarian/230600#230600) , with the imposition of the extra constraint that all diagonal elements must be 1.

So pick a minimum eigenvalue value, say mineig = 1e-10, and solve the convex Semidefinite Programming (SDP) problem as follows:

Let C = original n by n "correlation" matrix.
Solve for D, which will be the closest (per the Frobenius norm) correlation matrix to C having minimum eigenvalue of mineig.

In CVX, this would look like:

```
cvx_begin
variable D(n,n)
minimize(norm(D-C,'fro'))
lambda_min(D) >= mineig
diag(D) == 1
cvx_end
```

Here is an example run:
C is the original matrix, and has minimum eigenvalue = -1.0e-8.
D is the correlation matrix found as above, using mineig = 1e-10, and has minimum eigenvalue 1.0e-10.

C =

```
   1.000000000000000   0.775392316842042   0.775915347375462  -0.775460000000000
   0.775392316842042   1.000000000000000   0.587465374971244  -1.000000000000000
   0.775915347375462   0.587465374971244   1.000000000000000  -0.587459134116206
  -0.775460000000000  -1.000000000000000  -0.587459134116206   1.000000000000000
```

D =

```
   1.000000000000000   0.775392316905840   0.775915347450035  -0.775460000057614
   0.775392316905840   1.000000000000000   0.587465375009171  -0.999999989530503
   0.775915347450035   0.587465375009171   1.000000000000000  -0.587459134157367
  -0.775460000057614  -0.999999989530503  -0.587459134157367   1.000000000000000
```

D - X =

```
   1.0e-07 *
                   0   0.000637978558871   0.000745732364749  -0.000576140246622
   0.000637978558871                   0   0.000379269948780   0.104694971581054
   0.000745732364749   0.000379269948780                   0  -0.000411605194373
  -0.000576140246622   0.104694971581054  -0.000411605194373                   0
```

No element of D is more than 1.05e-8 different than the corresponding element of C.

eig(C) =

```
  -0.000000010368721
   0.171424190788319
   0.566827871126914
   3.261747948453490
```

eig(D) =

```
   0.000000000100778
   0.171424189980178
   0.566827867004568
   3.261747942914477
```

No eigenvalue of D is more than 1.05e-8 different than the corresponding element of C.

Here is the inverse of C

```
   1.0e+07 *
   0.000000001185191  -0.001409651498643   0.000000012853632  -0.001409643028590
  -0.001409651498643  -4.821534275445975   0.000735529929189  -4.822195310021794
   0.000000012853632   0.000735529929189   0.000000139399859   0.000735621788386
  -0.001409643028590  -4.822195310021794   0.000735621788386  -4.822856184065902
```

Note that 2 of the diagonal elements are negative: Ouch!!

Here is the inverse of D

```
   1.0e+09 *
   0.000000428103881   0.001450242932478  -0.000000223256533   0.001450443740640
   0.001450242932478   4.960731035829519  -0.000756759768677   4.961411023839190
  -0.000000223256533  -0.000756759768677   0.000000117959798  -0.000756863590705
   0.001450443740640   4.961411023839190  -0.000756863590705   4.962091107569242
```

All the diagonal elements are positive.  Yippee.

Wait a minute. Not so fast. What if we chose a different minimum eigenvalue for D, say 1e-6, instead of 1e-10.

Here is the partial correlation matrix using D (mineig = 1e-10)

```
   1.000000000000000   0.995160970407181  -0.993487907487549   0.995162354269721
   0.995160970407181   1.000000000000000  -0.989277623628771   0.999999999746921
  -0.993487907487549  -0.989277623628771   1.000000000000000  -0.989277740783460
   0.995162354269721   0.999999999746921  -0.989277740783460   1.000000000000000
```

Here is the partial correlation matrix using mineig = 1e-6

```
   1.000000000000000   0.100512651870996  -0.629191171229188   0.101907771942626
   0.100512651870996   1.000000000000000  -0.067837697192938   0.999997491360146
  -0.629191171229188  -0.067837697192938   1.000000000000000  -0.067917378792838
   0.101907771942626   0.999997491360146  -0.067917378792838   1.000000000000000
```

Oh no, changing the minimum eigenvalue from 1e-10 to 1e-6 totally changed the partial correlation matrix.  And the D corresponding to mineig = 1e-6 has no element differing by more than 1e-6 from the D using mineig = 1e-10. If you have a minimum eigenvalue close to 0, things are very sensitive, and I wouldn't put much stock in any of the results.

Comment: $C_{i,i}^{-1}$ is the ${i,i}$ element of the $C^{-1}$ matrix, sorry for the notation. It's unlikely to be equal to $1$.

Comment: Major edits have now been made.