# Least squares regression when data has error bars

Tags: regression, least-squares, standard-error, generalized-least-squares

Suppose I have some data $(x_i,y_i)$. If we perform ordinary least squares, we can get standard errors of the slope and intercept using estimates like $\hat{Var}(\hat{\beta}) = \hat{\sigma}^2 (X^\top X)^{-1}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Finite_sample_properties) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/44841/21801)).

However, suppose each $y_i$ came with a standard error $s_i$, possibly from some previous procedure. How would we obtain standard errors of the ordinary least squares slope and intercept that account for the standard errors from $s_i$? Or should we use a different regression technique?

Comment: Do you mean, you have some regression model $y_i = \mathbf{x}_i' \mathbf{\beta} + \epsilon_i$ and for whatever reason, you know that the variance of $\epsilon_i$ is $\sigma^2_i$, that is, (i) the variance of the residual is different for different observations (ii) you know what the variance for each observation is? Is this correct?

Comment: @MatthewGunn Yes, I think that is what I mean, up to the fact that $s_i^2$ may only be an estimate of the true $\sigma_i^2$. But we can temporarily consider the simpler case where $\sigma_i^2$ is known for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume regression model:
$$ y_i = \mathbf{x}'_i \boldsymbol{\beta} + \epsilon_i$$

Let $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ be your vector of error terms.

If you know that $ \mathrm{Var}\left(\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right) = \Omega$, for example:

$$ \Omega = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_1 & 0 & 0& \ldots&0\\0 &\sigma^2_2 & 0 & \ldots&0\\ 0 & 0 &\sigma^2_3& \ldots & 0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots &\ldots&0\\0&0&0&0&\sigma^2_n\end{bmatrix} $$
Then you can more [efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)) estimate $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ using [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares).

The estimator $\hat{\mathbf{b}}$ for GLS is given by:

$$\hat{\mathbf{b}} = \left(X'\Omega^{-1} X \right)^{-1}\left(X'\Omega^{-1} \mathbf{y} \right) $$

The basic idea with GLS is to give observations that are more precisely observed higher weight. **The danger of this approach of course is that if $\Omega$ is *not correct*, you can end up with something far worse than the equal weighting of regular OLS.**

Note also that [weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) (as what would occur for this $\Omega$), is a special case of GLS.

### If you just want to use OLS estimation but calculate standard errors assuming you know $\mathrm{Var}\left(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\right)$

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}\left( \hat{\mathbf{b}}_{OLS} \right) &= \mathrm{Var}\left( \left(X'X \right)^{-1}X'\left(X\mathbf{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right) \right)\\
&=\left(X'X \right)^{-1}X' \mathrm{Var}\left( \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right) X \left(X'X \right)^{-1} \\
&=\left(X'X \right)^{-1}X' \Omega X \left(X'X \right)^{-1} 
\end{align*}

The variance of the GLS estimator is given by:

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}\left( \hat{\mathbf{b}}_{GLS} \right) &= \mathrm{Var}\left( \left(X'\Omega^{-1} X \right)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1}\left(X\mathbf{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right) \right)\\
&=\left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1} \mathrm{Var}\left( \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \right) \Omega^{-1} X \left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1} \\
&=\left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1} \Omega\Omega^{-1} X \left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1} \\
&=\left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1} X \left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1}\\
&=\left(X'\Omega^{-1}X \right)^{-1}  
\end{align*}

Comment: Is the variance of the weighted least squares estimator the following?
$$
Var(\hat{b}) = (X^\top \Omega^{-1} X)^{-1} X^\top \Omega^{-1} Var(\epsilon) \Omega^{-1} X(X^\top \Omega^{-1} X)^{-1} = (X^\top \Omega^{-1} X)^{-1}
$$

Comment: @angryavian Yes, my typos should be fixed and the variance is given in my answer now too.

Comment: I think if you have a ["square root"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238977/127790) so that $\Omega^{-1}=W^TW$, then I *think* the GLS problem for $(X,y,\Omega)$ is equivalent to an OLS problem for $(\hat{X},\hat{y})=(WX,Wy)$.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Yes, it seems to be discussed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares#Properties).

Comment: @matthew I had some typos of my own as well, sorry. Thank you so much for your thorough explanations/references! Very much appreciated.