# Maximum Likelihood Fit for Non-Linear Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

I am reading the blog on [Bayesian priors and overfitting](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-truth-about-bayesian-priors-and-overfitting-84e24d3a1153) and it mentions that assume that a data is generated by the following function:

$$y_t=\sin\left(\dfrac{x_t}{10}\right)+ \cos\left(z_t\right)+5d_t+4+\epsilon_t$$

Then it mentiones the following:

> It features a cyclic process with one event represented by the variable $\mathbf{d}$. There is only 1 observation of that event so it means that maximum likelihood will always assign everything to this variable that cannot be explained by other data.

I did not understand what is meant by this whole sentence. So essentially we are generating $y_t$ by recording the values such as $x_t, z_t,d_t,\epsilon_t$ overtime and then plotting the $y$ vs $t$ right? now does that statement mean that we only have a single value recorded for d? And what does MLE will assign everything to this variable that cannot be explained by other data mean?

I would appreciate if a concrete formulation of MLE can be provided for the equation above as the original author did not provide any in the post.

Comment: +1 I had supposed your question would be answered by reading the source, but that's not the case: it is inherently vague and requires the reader to surmise the details.  My best guess is that "$d_t$" may mean something like the Kronecker delta $\delta(t-70).$

Comment: @whuber I believe that "$d_t$" here is simply a normal variable. The notion I got is that only single value has been recorded for this variable, instead of multiple over time and this makes sense if a "process" has multiple sensor nodes and one sensor node is faulty.

Comment: Your source never uses the word "Normal" and mentions "Gaussian" only once concerning a different issue, so any assumption of Normality would be reading a great deal into that article!

Comment: I suspect "$d_t$" stands for "dummy variable (that takes on the value $1$ at observation $t$ and $0$ otherwise)".

Comment: @jbowman yes $d_t$ is a dummy variable but not sure if it is binary as the question I am asking is about MLE pertaining to nonlinear regression and how the MLE assigns everything to this variable that cannot be explained by other variable. So in a way i abstracted the problem to understand how MLE for nonlinear regression is carried out and if we have only one reading for $d_t$ how does it affect learned parameters

Comment: Hi: It is a dummy variable but it only takes one the value of 1 at the time ( approximately )  $t = $ 70. Everywhere else it's zero. So, that means that, when the likelihood is built, the coefficient of $d_t$ only enters one time which is at $t =  $ 70. I didn't read the rest but, since $d_t$ only enters once, that's the only "chance" the algorithm has to deal with the fact that the response is larger at that point. So, it ends up putting a large weight on that coefficient. I didn't read the rest but I assume that the writer goes on about how bayesian avoids this problem ?

Comment: Hi Again: I would take what I said with a tablespoon of salt because he says that $d$ is a parameter  which to me sounds like the coefficient, $5$,  is known already ? A very not clear description on my second reading. If he's estimating the $d_t$ coefficient, then I believe my argument. If he's not, forget what I said.

Comment: If you would like information on non-linear regression, start with this search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+regression+nonlinear.  I agree this is a strange model and it is not expressed in a way that helps make its points, but we could understand "$d_t$" as having a parameter--let's call it $\theta$--in the sense that $d_t = \theta \delta_{t-70}$ (sometimes called a "pulse" at time $70$). That interpretation makes some sense out of the article.

Comment: @whuber: Assuming what you said is correct, then I'll stand by what I said in my original comment : $\theta$ gets overestimated because there's only one observation associated with the event. Of course, I'm not saying this but I think that's what the author is saying.

Comment: It's annoying to see this question pop back up every few hours because of trivial edits.  I appreciate that you want to improve it, but at this point it looks like you're just trying to game the system to get attention.

Comment: @whuber, its unfortunate that you feel that way. This site is meant for obtaining help, and measures to seek that shouldnt be worthy of "unupvote" from the moderators.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers for some constructive approaches to get answers.

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER: Just seeing this now so it's a late reply. The MLE for a non-linear model is really no different than an MLE for linear models. One builds the likelihood and then maximizes it. The only difference is that building the likelihood in the non-linear case is sometimes a little more complicated. If you have access, Harvey's "Economic Time Series Analysis" has many examples of building likelihoods for non-linear time series models. I highly recommend it. It's terse which can make it a little difficult but, with effort, very useful.

Comment: @mlofton so i got the book, could you please recommend relevant pages to read as it looks quite daunting with formulas.

Comment: that's great. let me take a look and get back to you. It is a terse book that packs TONS of info on one page. But, if you work at it, it's worth it.

Comment: Hi: There are various examples on pages 268, 273, 279 and 300. But if you write a new question with the model for which you're trying to build the likelihood, hopefully myself or someone else can show you how to build it ? Is it the model above in your original question ? It's not clear from your question what the model is because, in your question, you kind of asked something else. ( interpretation of what the author is saying ).

Comment: @mlofton yes indeed, the model in the question is what I want to fit MLE to. The question has two parts one to clarify the sentence about the delta which you already did, the second is the formulations to fit MLE to this equation. My apologies if this wasn't clear in the question, I can rephrase it so this can be answered as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I didn't understand that you were referring to that model specifically. Normally, to calculate the likelihood of a model, you calculate the residuals and then plug them into the concentrated likelihood ( concentrated just means that you get rid of the $\hat{\sigma}^2$ part of the likelihood by substituting whatever the MLE is for $\sigma^2$ ). But, assuming the residuals are normally distributed,  we can cheat a little and just minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{\epsilon_t}^2$. ( this is the same as maximizing the likelihood but it only works because you have the normal as the density ).

A) Now,  Assuming I understand what the blogger is doing ( which could be a big assumption ) your model is:

$y_t = sin(\frac{x_t}{10}) + cos(z_t) + \beta \times d_t + 4 + \epsilon_t$.

Note that the only unknown parameter in your model is $\beta$.

So, $\hat{\epsilon}_t = y_t - (sin(\frac{x_t}{10}) + cos(z_t) + \beta \times d_t + 4 ) $

For $t = 1, \ldots n$, you should have all the terms above above that allow you to calculate $\hat{\epsilon}_t ~\forall t$

So, you calculate $\hat{\epsilon}_t$ for each $t$, then sum the squares of it and minimize the sum. Notice that the sum of the residuals squared is a function of $\beta$ and nothing else so what you're really doing is finding the $\hat\beta$ that minimizes the sum of the residuals squared. This is done using an iterative numerical procedure. Do you use R or Rcpp ? My description is general but, if you use R, then there are tons of examples on the net that show you how to implement an optimization that minimizes a function which is exactly what you're trying to do because the function is the sum of the residuals squared. Note that minimizing the sum is an iterative numerical procedure. The function optim() in R is usually used for doing this.

B) Important point: Since the only parameter is $\beta$, your model really isn't non-linear. ( again, this is assuming I understand it ). So could turn the model into a linear regression model by just subtracting everything on the RHS from $y_t$ except for the term involving $\beta$. Specifically, let

$y^{*}_t = y_t - (sin(\frac{x_t}{10}) + cos(z_t) + 4 ) $

Then, the model can be written as $y^{*}_t = \beta \times d_{t} + \epsilon_t$.

But the latter is just a linear regression model which can be estimated by a call to the lm function in R. If there were coefficients in front of the sine or cosine terms, you could still use the same reformulation described in B) so, atleast as far as I understand, you really have a linear regression model and don't need to worry about non-linear regression and don't have to concern yourself with what described in A). But it still might be slightly useful to you ?

Comment: We are almost there, so in the Blog the author produces the data using the function above where $x_t, d_t, z_t, \epsilon_t$ are all "known to the author" also called "truth" in the blog, once the data is generated from the known values, the author is now treating $x_t, d_t, z_t, \epsilon_t$ as unknown and using MLE applied to "Data" to determine their values assuming the model as shown in the equation above. Now the small confusion was that the value of $d_t$ was only utilized during t=70, which is cleared

Comment: So to simplify the problem statement is that "given data and the model" estimate the true values on $x_t , d_t, z_t, \epsilon_t$ by performing MLE fit. The true value of **d** as mentioned in the blog is 5

Comment: now i am assuming that the data was generated by fluctuating the values of $x_t, d_t, z_t, \epsilon_t$ slightly or by a small variance such as 5.1,5.3,5.2... and then using the "data and the nonlinear equation" to determine the mean of the values "$x_t, d_t, z_t, \epsilon_t$" that generated the data by performing MLE and then contrasting it with Bayesian way, but i am only interested in MLE for now.

Comment: also as i understand it the data utilized for $d_t$ could have been 0,0,0,0,5,0,0 hence the peak at t=70ish

Comment: @GENIVI_LEARNER: As I understand it, everything is known, EXCEPT for the coefficient of $d_t$. So, my description is for estimating the coefficient of $d_t$, namely $\beta$.  Does that make sense ? Again, this is assuming that I understand what's going on. I find the author's description confusing so I'm not going by his description but rather what I think he means.

Comment: yes the description of author is quite confusing without concrete formulations so we will leave it there. I shall review this now.

Comment: hi: yes, it's confusing. based on my understanding of it, my explanation is correct. Keep in mind that the model is linear. The sine and cosine terms don't make it non-linear. So, disregard A) in my explanation, You can estimate the model using a straightforward regression call.